# Display specific lines from a .txt file to a listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, text-files

I am trying to display specific lines that i have now stored in an array from a text file into a list box.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\James Dunn\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Assignment 2\Assignment 2\MyJukeBox\bin\Debug\Media\Genre.txt");
mediaLibrary[0] = genreListBox;
for (int l = 3; l < lines.Length; l++)
{
   mediaLibrary[0].Items.Add(lines[l]);
}
genreListBox.Items.Add(mediaLibrary[0]);
```

This code so far displays all but the first 3 lines of text. how do i get it to stop after its displayed the lines I require? I have tried using the following in the for loop but it gives me errors.

```
int ll = 6; != lines.Length;
```

My txt file layed out like so

```
3
2
Other
Big Bad John (1961) - Jimmy Dean.mp3
My Ding A Ling - Chuck Berry.mp3
2
Rap
2pac-ghost.mp3
B.I.G-Spit Your Game.mp3
1
Rock
Linkin park-Numb.mp3
```

Comment: What lines do you require? Do they always sit at a specific index?

Comment: What determines the amount of or which lines to display?

Comment: Ill post the layout of the file and yes the file is unchanging

Comment: I require the tracks from the first genre so lines 4 and 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by using an if statement and adding break.

```
{
// Adding first genre title
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\James Dunn\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Assignment 2\Assignment 2\MyJukeBox\bin\Debug\Media\Genre.txt");
for (int l = 3; l < lines.Length; l++)
{
mediaLibrary[0].Items.Add(lines[l]);
if (l == 4)
break;
}
genreTitleTextBox.(mediaLibrary[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Skip()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [Take()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) if the elements are always in the same position.

So if you always wanted the 3rd and 4th lines you would do

```
mediaLibrary[0].Items.AddRange(lines.Skip(2).Take(2).ToArray<object>());
```

Comment: The error i receive is Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'object[]'

Comment: Convert the `IEnumerable<string>` to an `object[]` e.g. `.ToArray<object>();`. See my edit.